# SharePoint 2007 using '~language' dynamic token stays en-US even when site is in zh-CN

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

In the master page for a SharePoint site, a CSS file is referenced in the `<head>` section as

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/~language/Core Styles/style.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

my understanding is that the site will convert the dynamic token to the language of the site, such that if viewing in English, `~language` will be replaced with `en-US` and if the site is in Chinese, it would be `zh-CN`. What is happening is that the dynamic token is always exchanged with `en-US`, and never shows `zh-CN`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/style.css"/>
```

I have ensured that the master page has both variations enabled....does anyone have *any* idea?

Comment: I've done something very similar before but in a different way. Before I answer can you tell me what language setting are you trying to detect? The regional setting of the SharePoint site/web? 
or the user's regional setting?

Comment: Hi Zeb - I'm setting the language by using a dropdown which executes code to set the thread culture info for Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. I have also played with setting System.Globalization.CultureInfo for SPWeb locales. When viewing the source for the page I see that some items are looking to /_layouts/2052/ after selecting Chinese, but the majority of the CSS files are still pointing to /Style%20Library/en-US/. Can you tell me what your approach was?